# Colab: How to speed up training? How to load data from google drive to Colab efficiently?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, ram, disk

I stored my data on Google Drive and mount the data to Colab by this code:

```
from google.colab import drive 
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

That works, but training for example a neural network is very slow. Now, I was wondering, if there is another option to get the data on Colab?

Note: I cannot store all the data on Colab at once because it is too big. So, I need to train my network batch-wise.

To get the data batch-wise I use a customized `DataGenerator` using `keras.utils.Sequence`.

```
class DataGenerator(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return math.ceil(len(self.x) / self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_x = [imread(file_name) for file_name in batch_x]
        batch_x = np.array(batch_x)
        batch_x = batch_x * 1./255
        batch_y = self.y[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_y = np.array(batch_y)

        return batch_x, batch_y
```

I am using `TensorFlow` for the configuration of the model.

The dataset contains more than 180.000 images of license plates, for which I would like to recognize the ground truth text, the image paths are the `x_set` data. `y_set` are the according labels for every image, which are one-hot encoded.